# Access to the v4 TPUs

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

For our purposes, we would really like to have access to the v4 TPUs. We found the Google form and filled it out a few weeks ago, but it seems we've thrown a dart into an abyss, with no response. Is there any way to accelerate/another method to get v4 TPUs? If so, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because outsiders to GCP don't have an insight into the internal workings of the company, so this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/v4-users-guide#request_more_tpu_quota), you have to request more TPU quota.

The default quota allocation for Cloud TPU v4 is zero for all projects. Request quota by contacting your sales representative. following the instructions in the [quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quota#quota_for_single_device_tpu_types).

Or try to contact them with this [link](https://cloud.google.com/contact).